# Installshield 2015 : displaying a simple installation report at end of installation process

Tags: installation, report, installshield

I'm using Installshield 2015  Premier Edition to create a MSI release from an Installscript MSI type project. The MSI installs several .NET application prerequisites and 5 .NET applications.

I'm kinda new to IS2015 and was wondering how to display an installation report at end of installation process to the end-user?

The installation report must sum up if all files were copied, if some prerequisites were correctly installed , and if scheduled tasks were installed.

This is the Installscript code which I use to launch the scheduled task creation :

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// OnFirstUIAfter
//
// The OnFirstUIAfter event called by the framework after the file transfer
// of the setup when the setup is running in first install mode. By default
// this event displays UI that informs the end user that the setup has been
// completed successfully.
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
function OnFirstUIAfter()
   string szMessage, szTitle;
   number nResult;
begin   

//if (SYSINFO.WINNT.bWinServer2003 && SYSINFO.WINNT.nServicePack > 1 ) then 
if (SYSINFO.WINNT.bWinServer2003) then     
    LaunchAppAndWait(TARGETDIR ^ "CreateSchedulingWinServer2003.bat", TARGETDIR, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT); 
else
    LaunchAppAndWait(TARGETDIR ^ "CreateScheduling.bat", TARGETDIR, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);  
endif; 

    LaunchAppAndWait(TARGETDIR ^ "RemoveSchedulingFile.bat", TARGETDIR, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);  
end;
```

Thanks you kindly,

Comment: You can easily add custom dialogs and add text elements with property as source. During your setup you can add text to this property via customactions. At the end of the setup you can show this dialog.

Comment: MSI installs are transactional. They either completely work, or fail and roll back, restoring the system to its previous state. There is no case where some files get copied and some don't, unless  of course you didn't select all the features. If it's important that scheduled tasks are created (by your custom action) then make them return an error result so that the install rolls back.

Comment: I know that files copy is pretty straightforward in IS, so far, it has never failed during installation process on a qualification environment. My client has requested that an installation report should be displayed at end of installation process and it's really embarrassing me because it's kinda redundant ( file copy never fails, reporting scheduled tasks creation test is awkward ).